Is it possible to export PowerBI Table's group/measure as text
Is it possible to export the definition of a Group column of a table in Powerbi, some kind of text based (maybe json or similar) format.
I need to extract the group names and the items belonging to that group.
I tried to figure out if Dax Studio has a management view that I can see the definition but I could not find a management view that has this information. Also in powerbi I was not able to find a way to see the definition of a group as DAX format or in any other format.
See image below.

